# Incomplete SQL error in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I've a SQLite script which initializes a DB (SQLite 3.8.2), created as follows:

```
sqlite3 -init database_creation.sql sample.db
```

The script file is like:

```
 // Some `CREATE TABLE` statements

 CREATE TRIGGER update_totalprice AFTER UPDATE
   OF price, amount, boxes ON product
   BEGIN UPDATE product SET totalprice = price * boxes * amount
   WHERE idproduct = NEW.idproduct; END

 // Some `INSERT` statements.
```

But it generates the following error:

```
Error: incomplete SQL: CREATE TRIGGER update_totalprice AFTER UPDATE
   OF price, amount, boxes ON product
   BEGIN UPDATE product SET totalprice = price * boxes * amount
   WHERE idproduct = NEW.idproduct; END

// The rest of the file to the end.
```

I'm sure there're syntax errors nor creating the tables neither inserting the test rows, because if I comment the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement all works perfectly fine, and I don't find the syntax error either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem was pretty simple. I though the "END" keyword was enough to mark the end of the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement (even more knowing that the `UPDATE` statement has already its own ';'), but after `END`, another `;` is required:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER update_totalprice
 AFTER UPDATE OF price, amount, boxes ON product
 BEGIN
   UPDATE product SET totalprice = price * boxes * amount
   WHERE idproduct = NEW.idproduct;
 END;
```